# Contentful + Algolia Search using Gatsby Image

Tags: gatsby, algolia, contentful

My Gatsby/Contentful blog is using Algolia to search through blog posts. Everything is working just fine, besides displaying images.

This is the Webhook Payload that Ive created in Contentful by using the Algolia template:

```
{
  "title": "{ /payload/fields/title/en-US}",
  "slug": "{ /payload/fields/slug/en-US}",
  "price": "{ /payload/fields/price/en-US}",
  "category": "{ /payload/fields/category/en-US}",
  "usages": "{ /payload/fields/usages/en-US}",
  "rating": "{ /payload/fields/rating/en-US}",
  "image": "https:{ /payload/fields/image/fields/file/url}"
}
```

My algolia query looks like this:

```
algolia.js



const contentfulQuery = `
{
    allContentfulStrains {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        price
        category
        image {
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

function pageToAlgoliaRecords({ id, title, price, image }) {
  return { objectID: id, title, price, image }

}

const queries = [
  {
    query: contentfulQuery,
    transformer: ({ data }) => data.allContentfulStrains.nodes.map(pageToAlgoliaRecords),
  }
]

module.exports = queries
```

Now when I type gatsby build the data algolia is receiving is not structured right. View the image below. I want the structure to be - image:image.url so I can get the url of the image and past it in the hit component to display the images.

[image: algolia search image query]

Is there something wrong with my query?

I really dont know what Im doing wrong..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Algolia image and media queries needs to be populated with the same data as the [Gatsby image fragments](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#fragments) despite not supporting fragments *per se*. In your case it would look like:

```
image {
  childImageSharp {
    fluid {
      aspectRatio
      src
      srcSet
      sizes
      originalImg
      originalName
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, your `transformer` looks fine to me.

Checking my configuration for Algolia I've realized that all my images paths are set locally (with `/static`). I guess Algolia needs to be populated with static assets rather than an outer URL. Try adding the `downloadLocal: true` in your configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: `your_space_id`,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        downloadLocal: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

And use a [`localFile`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#download-assets-for-static-distribution) query for distribution:

```
  localFile {
    publicURL
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 500) {
          aspectRatio
          src
          srcSet
          sizes
          originalImg
          originalName
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ive tried your approach. I changed the payload in Contentful to:   "image": "https:{ /payload/fields/image/fields/fluid/src}" and added your query, but in Algolia it still looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbCqM.png

Comment: I guess that the issue comes from the need for Algolia to index the static (downloaded) assets. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So ive added  `downloadLocal: true` but it throughs in this error:   GraphQLError: Cannot query field "localFile" on type "ContentfulStrains".

Comment: Also, how does your payload looks like in Contentful for an image? Do you use the Algolia Webhook in Contentful?

Comment: I'm using markdown files with static images from a CMS but the idea still the same. Try your GraphiQL playground in order to get the local path.

Comment: I got the local path but im still not achieving the right result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJTto.png , There must be a problem with the Contentful Algolia Payload.

Comment: Im trying this webhook:  "image": "{ /payload/fields/image/fields/fluid/src}" but somehow its not working..